# does somebody know whether a linux / opensource driver does exist for the apple xserve 3,1 raid controller?

Tags: linux, hardware-raid, apple, xserve

I'm trying to install linux on a apple xserve 3,1 which comes with some strange raid controller that does not get detected by linux. `lspci` is telling me:

`01:00.0 RAID bus controller: Apple Computer Inc. Device 008a (rev c8)`

I am assuming that this is a qlogic raid controller, but none of the qlogic drivers work.

The only other output that I get on the command line that might be related to this controller is:

`pci 0000:01:00.0: vpd r/w failed. This is likely a firmware bug on this device. Contact the card vendor for a firmware upgdate.`

any hints on how to talk to this thing are welcome!

**EDIT:** I also tried to get vmware on this running, since the HCL states that xserve 3,1 is supported (http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=server&productid=20234), however, the vmware installer doesn't see any hard drives either. This seems to be a known problem http://communities.vmware.com/message/1901726, http://communities.vmware.com/message/1817235

Comment: Apple used to ship LSI Megaraids in the past (see http://images.apple.com/server/docs/Using_Hardware_RAID.pdf), this might be one of them.  But the standard driver probably won't attach because of non-standard PCI ID.

Comment: This device still doesn't appear in the pci.ids database. If this really is an LSI Megaraid, you could try editing the driver source code to add its pci ids to the supported devices and recompile the module.

Comment: @wazoox I can't recompile the module on a boot disk - is there a way to initialize the module and pass the pci-id to it?

Comment: From [this post][http://staff.blog.ui.ac.id/t.a.sabastian/2012/03/16/taming-the-apple-xserve-server-2nd-edition/] it looks like this isn't an LSI after all. My bet: this uses custom firmware, and won't ever work unless you're ready to spend serious time and are a knowledgeable kernel developer. You'd better completely forget it IMO.